# caching localtime_r() is it worth it?

Tags: c

is it worth keeping a local copy of `struct tm` and update it only when required; below func is not thread safe... also I've seen only 6 to 7% of CPU time can be saved...

```
struct tm* custom_localtime (time_t now_sec)
{

    static time_t cache_sec;
    static struct tm tms;

    if (now_sec != cache_sec) {
        cache_sec = now_sec;
        localtime_r(&cache_sec, &(tms));
    }

    return(&tms);
}
```

Additional details:
- my app makes more than 3000/sec calls to `localtime_r()`

found out at least 33% CPU time saving when I cache time-stamp strings of the format `"2011-12-09 10:32:45"` againt `time_t` seconds

thank you all nos, asc99c and Mircea.

Comment: What are your criteria for worthiness?

Comment: to save time in a scenario where I make a call to localtime_r() more than 3000/sec for writing logs etc...

Comment: If the time you will save matters to you, then do it. If it doesn't matter, don't do it. How can *we* decide if the difference matters to *you*?

Comment: Time the code where you loop 100000000 times with and without caching,   that should tell you roughly how much it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably have mentioned the 3000/s call rate in your question!  Do it.  I recently was profiling generation of a screen which was calling localtime approx 1,000,000 * 10,000 times.

The nested loops could have been improved substantially with a bit of thought, but what I saw was about 85% of CPU time was used by localtime.  Simply caching the result so it was only called 10,000 times cut 85% of the time off page generation, and that made it easily fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

"Avoiding a library function call that's not really needed" is worth it, of couse. The rest is only your tradeoff between memory and speed.

Since you're calling this 3000/second, you might want to go even further and put this function as `static inline` in a header and also (if using GCC) use branch prediction hints for the conditional, stating that taking it is "unlikely":

```
if (__builtin_expect(now_sec != cache_sec, 0))
```